# Adding new methods to LINQ to SQL generated classes

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to LINQ.  I just dragged all my database tables onto the designer in a LINQ to SQL dbml.  All my relationships are correct and look nice in the designer.  I am able to pull data using simple LINQ code.  I want to add my own methods now but don't want to blow away my changes if (when) I need to regenerate my dbml.  I am guessing I just create a new class file and setup partial classes of the generated classes.  Is this correct?  For example, I have a generated class called **SystemUser** which contains the columns ***SystemUserId, Username, Password, PersonId, SecurityQuestionId, SecurityQuestionResponse***.  I want to add a method called ***void Authenticate()*** and a new property called ***bool Authenticated***.  Basically I want to pass in a username and password to ***Authenticate()*** and set the ***Authenticated*** property based on finding a matching user, etc.  Where and how would I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The LINQ-generated classes are partial classes, meaning you can extend them by creating your own [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882671.aspx) or [partial methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546176.aspx).

In your case, you can create a partial class for your SystemUser, and then add your method(s) in there. They will not be overwritten if the DBML file is regenerated.

Something like:

```
public partial class SystemUser
{
    public bool Authenticated { get; set; }

    void Authenticate()
    {
        //Perform custom logic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: All the answers were helpful, but I liked the links you provided.  I am new to StackOverflow so I think you win!?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using a Partial class... it might fit your situation very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your class to have a new method you are correct create a new file and use  partial class.